# How do I get the List values of a property of a class?

Tags: c#, list, loops, foreach, properties

I'm trying to iterate through the properties of a class.
It's working fine until i get a property which is defined as a list.
Is there an easy way to handle this because I'm pretty sure, there is but
unfortunately I'm not able to find the solution.

When I iterate through the properties the right values for the specific class will be shown, but only if it is a single value, I can't get any list values.
if I use the property iteration, the property list will be shown as

> System.Collections.Generic.List`1[System.Double].

A little background about my program. I dynamically create a `List` of my class with different values for the properties, so it's important that I get the right values for the right class.

```
...

for(int j = 0; j<intensityList.Count; j++) {

                getIntensityofMode(intensityList[j]);
                Report.Log(ReportLevel.Info, "");
                Console.ReadLine();
            }
        }
        public void getIntensityofMode(HelpingClasses.IntensityData mode) {

            Type type = typeof(HelpingClasses.IntensityData);
            PropertyInfo[] properties = type.GetProperties();
            foreach (PropertyInfo property in properties)
            {
                if(property.GetValue(mode, null) != null) {
                    Report.Log(ReportLevel.Info, property.Name + " = " + property.GetValue(mode, null));

                    if(property.PropertyType.IsGenericType &&
                       property.PropertyType.GetGenericTypeDefinition() == typeof(List<>)) {
                        Report.Log(ReportLevel.Info,"its a list");

                        foreach() 
//iterate through the property which is a list and holds several values
                        {
                        }
                    }
                } else {
                    Report.Log(ReportLevel.Info, property.Name + " = NaN");
                }
            }
```

So I think, I just have to write one line in the `foreach` loop to get what I'm trying to get but I don't know how to handle it.

```
//variables
        public string TxVoltagePulseMode{ get; set; }
        public double TxVoltagePulseDB{ get; set; }
        public double TxVoltagePulseVoltage{ get; set; }
        public List<double> TxFocusdepth{ get; set; }
```

So everything works with the code except for `TxFocusdepth`.

Comment: Check if the property is a collection. And if it is, feed the value to a for or foreach loop.

Comment: yeah, i know the steps, but i dont know how to implement it..

Comment: because i already check if its a list, but i dont get the values of the list

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can ignore the fact that it is a generic list entirely and just treat it as a non-generic IList.

...

```
for(int j = 0; j<intensityList.Count; j++) {

            getIntensityofMode(intensityList[j]);
            Report.Log(ReportLevel.Info, "");
            Console.ReadLine();
        }
    }

public void getIntensityofMode(HelpingClasses.IntensityData mode) {

    Type type = typeof(HelpingClasses.IntensityData);
    PropertyInfo[] properties = type.GetProperties();
    foreach (PropertyInfo property in properties)
    {
        if(property.GetValue(mode, null) != null) {
            var value = property.GetValue(mode, null);
            // Test if it is IList and cast it if so
            if (value is IList e) {
                // Print the value of elements in the enumerable list
                foreach (var v in e) {
                    Report.Log(ReportLevel.Info, property.Name + " = " + v.ToString());
                }
            } else {
               Report.Log(ReportLevel.Info, property.Name + " = " + value);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: hey, thanks for the fast answer. unfortunately it doesnt work, it only returns the single values, but the list property values. 
so my output is 

 TxVoltagePulseMode = A
 TxVoltagePulseDB = 0
 TxVoltagePulseVoltage = 4.731

but it wont return the list then 

although it has to be mention for other people, i can use the IEnumerable only in c# 7 or above. because i work with ranorex and it uses c# 5 at first, so at the start it didnt work

Comment: ok im sorry, the list were empty the whole time.
but still the problem stays the same, it says:  System.Collections.Generic.List`1[System.Double] 
but 4 times, what is exactly the amount of values

so the solution above isnt working

Comment: Hey i found the solution!!

thanks the code above works until one point.

its v.toString() because you want the values of var v and not from value.
thats why it was not working.

can you edit your answer? i will mark it at right, and thanks so much

Comment: also its IList and not ienumerable because it its ienumerable , it will return also every char in a string as a single value
but with IList, it will check, wether the value is a IList and then it will return the values of the List

Comment: @MinhTV Edit approved. Thanks for following up.